# Is there a desktop twitter client that has a built in browser?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, twitter

I really like the iPad version of twitter, in that it opens up links to the right of your stream. No need to go anywhere else. Of course, the new browser based client opens photos on the right. But Twitter for Mac only opens up links in your regular browser.

Does anyone know of a desktop client that has its own built-in browser?

Comment: It's understandable to have the embedded browser in an iPad app, but why do you want an app-embedded browser on a Desktop app? I can only imagine (in my own setting), such a thing would cause me to forget which "browser" I was looking at a given page in.

Comment: I want Twitter to act more like Reeder. Simple as that. I want a stream or feed on the left, and then if a tweet has a link in it I want it to show up on the right. I don't want to necessarily click on links to be able to see what a link is about

Comment: @drury but you still have to click on the tweet to show the page…

Answer (score 1):

[Hibari](http://hibariapp.com/) gets you part of the way there. It shows inline image links in the timeline.

Personally, I don't see how loading other links automatically is all that desirable or safe.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of one with a built in browser but if you use Safari you could always install the Twitter pluggin. This provides you with the opportunity to read your stream right there in the browser so it's almost what you're looking for, just in the reverse direction. For Firefox there are a number of download add-ons that you can use to do the same, and for Chrome I would recommend TweetDeck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a desktop twitter client, but there are many plugins available for browsers that allow you to tweet and surf.  Check out the Firefox or Google Chrome plugins for a twitter client. Would this meet your needs?